# Can I hook up an LED to the power lines of a USB-A connector, in parallel, and expect the USB's function to be unimpared?

Tags: low-power, usb-pd

The title covers most of the question, but here's a simple schematic anyway:
[image: schematic]

The specific LED that I have is a [5V, 12mA red diode](https://nl.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Lumex/SSL-LX5093ID-5V?qs=sWJIHVaBZlA2Zl7G2f27uQ%3D%3D).

For this example, assume a USB 2.0 connection, which as per datasheet provides a maximum of 500mA. So another way of looking at this, is what is the minimum amount of current necessary for a USB port to have normal, unimpeded functionality, i.e. not result in any data loss? Are there other types of interference that such an LED may introduce, which would impact USB functionality?

Comment: Please be aware that the particular LED you listed has a series resistor built in. Without it (using any other LED) would result in your LED frying itself.

Comment: I actually wasn't aware that the LED features a built-in resistor. Where exactly is this listed? I can't seem to find it on either the website or the datasheet for it. Also how does this change the operation in my use case?

Comment: The giveaway is the fact the LED says 5 volts. You would have to know about LEDs to notice. A bare red LED has a voltage of about 1-2 volts and an exponential I/V curve, so a resistor is normally used as "ballast"

Comment: I see. The irony here is that I specifically chose this component *because* of its 5V forward voltage, believing that in doing so I avoid the need to include a resistor in my circuit, but I see now that its already included.

Comment: EE top tip: design for a regular LED with external resistor and you avoid the problem all together and have far more options for sourcing.

Comment: Having a generic resistor and generic LED might be cheaper as well, than a highly specialized LED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem with that. The power supply won't know what is drawing the current. Any other USB device you attach won't know that something else is using some of the power budget. The only time you'd have trouble would be if the load drew close to 500 mA.

The 500 mA is likely to have a wide tolerance and at current limit the voltage is likely to start to droop to 4.9 V, etc., rather than shut off suddenly at 500.00 mA. I wouldn't be surprised if you found that you could pull 600 mA without difficulty and I'm sure that many USB hubs that don't have external 5 V supplies are often overloaded and draw more power from the USB source than they should.

Comment: I believe that for my application I will never come close to the 500mA limit of the USB port, as I'm using this on a PCB which has a separate power-supply and bus for the higher power drawing components, so this is satisfactory. Thank you.